# We can't find products matching the selection

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, magento2.3, magento2.3.0

> I just updated to 2.3.0 and when I try to open any category page ->
> instead of filters I am getting "Compare products" and "My wishlist" +
> . instead of product list getting message "We can't find products
> matching the selection."

How can I solve/investigate this question?

Comment: Reindex & clear cache

Comment: i tried, it's not solving

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on the version you upgraded from it might be a missing stock source/default. Can't check right now but you should find two menu entries under shops or system.

**Edit:**

With Magento 2.3 a new feature called Multi Source Inventory was introduced. After an upgrade from a prior version you need to set a source and a default stock.
So the settings I mentioned can be found under `Stores > Inventory > Sources`. Here you need to configure a source.
Under `Stores > Inventory > Stocks` you need to apply default stock to your website.

It may also require a reindex.

Comment: Where is "Stores" ? Edit: He means "Shops"

Answer (score 12):

i was facing this challenge and was almost frustrated when i finally got how to fix it. For me I used this

i used the code below to view the table

```
sql command select *
from catalog_eav_attribute cea 
join eav_attribute ea
  on ea.attribute_id = cea.attribute_id 
  and backend_type in ('text', 'varchar')
where 
  cea.is_filterable = 1
```

and Set is_filterable to 0 to allow category pages to load.

```
update catalog_eav_attribute cea 
join eav_attribute ea
  on ea.attribute_id = cea.attribute_id 
  and backend_type in ('text', 'varchar')
set cea.is_filterable = 0
where 
  cea.is_filterable = 1
```

Reindex/Refresh Cache

```
magento indexer:reindex
magento cache:clean
magento cache:flush
```

i got the solution from this link, it was a very helpful solution....thank you doublesharp
[best solution ever](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/322516/magento-2-x-elasticsearch-category-products-not-showing?answertab=active#tab-top)

Comment: much appreciated this saved me!

Comment: Working perfectly Magento2.4.2 Thank you!

Comment: worked for in 2.4.2, thank you

Answer (score 8):

In my case I tried to re-index but noticed the index failed for esatic search:

*Catalog Search index exception: Could not ping search engine: No alive nodes found in your cluster*

**i resolved by running:**

sudo systemctl restart elasticsearch

php bin/magento indexer:reindex

php bin/magento cache:flush

Comment: worked for me.
sudo systemctl restart elasticsearch will work

Comment: this is it ! Make sure that elasticsearch is running and that magento connects to it (you may test it here: Admin -> Store -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Catalog -> Catalog Search)

Answer (score 6):

You have to recreate the inventory_Stock_1 view in Database. You can make it happen with an query (like this);

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW `inventory_stock_1` AS select
     distinct `legacy_stock_status`.`product_id` AS `product_id`,
     `legacy_stock_status`.`website_id` AS `website_id`,
     `legacy_stock_status`.`stock_id` AS `stock_id`,
     `legacy_stock_status`.`qty` AS `quantity`,
     `legacy_stock_status`.`stock_status` AS `is_salable`,
     `product`.`sku` AS `sku` from
     ( `cataloginventory_stock_status` `legacy_stock_status` join `catalog_product_entity` `product` on
         (( `legacy_stock_status`.`product_id` = `product`.`entity_id` )));
```

After that, you have to reindex Magento:

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Now all should be displayed and looks fine.

Hope it helps.

Comment: This worked for me

Comment: Work for me ! I had an error message with this particular table.

Answer (score 1):

Run this command to fix the issue `php bin/magento indexer:reindex`

Comment: Does not fix it for me.

Comment: me too. I guess the elasticsearch have problem

Answer (score 1):

Run this command to fix the issue `php bin/magento indexer:reindex`
worked for Me

Answer (score 1):

This may sound silly but make sure that both of these are set:

**Quantity** > 0

**Stock Status**: In Stock

It may be trivial, but knowing that you must explicitly set "In Stock" even though you've set Qty to a number higher than 0 can save much time.

Comment: Yes, this happened to me, as Magento 2 noob I spent an enormous amount of time trying to figure it out! Because there is no error in the logs.

Answer (score 0):

**In Category Enable Anchor in Display Setting.**

[image: Enable Anchor Tag]

**In Attribute set Filter with Results in Use in Layered Navigation.**

[image: Attribute]

**And then reindex it.
Hope it will work.**

Comment: No, it's not.
These steps are dont, but not solve this

Answer (score 0):

On version 2.4.2 if there's an error with your elastic search or if it's not running, then no categories will show.  Fix it and run upgrade, di:compile, clear cache again.