# We can't find products matching the selection in magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, elasticsearch, category-listing, php-7.2

On every listing page, I'm getting **We can't find products matching the selection**. I followed this also but dint helped [We can't find products matching the selection](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/263739/we-cant-find-products-matching-the-selection). I'm attaching a screenshot for your reference

[image]

I tried changing the **elasticsearch** version also but that also doesn't work. Currently, I'm using **elasticsearch** **6.8.x**. Please help.

**Note:** Every category has almost 1000s of products and all of them are enabled. I have done all settings from the backend that needs to be done to show products on the frontend.

Comment: tried re-indexing, flush cache ?

Comment: I did everything like reindexing, cache clean, cache flush, setup upgrade

Comment: in your admin in `Salable Quantity` column, can you positive qty in `Default Stock` ?

Comment: Where to find this?

Comment: in catalog -> products grid

Comment: Salable quantity for every product is more than 100

Comment: Try this - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/291190/magento2-enabling-elasticsearch-empties-all-categories/293001#293001  if Magento version matches. Check existing code before apply.

Comment: Thanks a lot @sandip it worked

Comment: @AjayKr you can upvote answer if the answer was helpful to you

Answer (score 0):

Check your CSV import file column "is_in_stock"  the correct value for in-stock items is '1' for out of stock the value is '0'

I changed this in the CSV, did another import, and all the stock is showing.
All I have to do now is get the images to display. thanks to Anna Gutmanska for this solution

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and it was resolved by [renaming the Elastic Search Index](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/332594/75553). I know this one is kind of old but it might help someone.

Answer (score 0):

Try to restart elasticsearch on your server.