# Elastic Search "We can't find products matching the selection" on every page

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to setup Elastic Search on an existing catalog that works fine under standard MySQL search. I go through the documentation and it seems straightforward. This is Magento 2.3.2 and ElasticSearch 6 (version 6.7.1).

The documentation says to just select it and reindex. It feels like there must be some extra step that I'm not clear on. After doing so, all I get on every category page is "We can't find products matching the selection."

I've done all of the basics (clearing all caches and temp files, reindexing). The solution found [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/291190/magento2-enabling-elasticsearch-empties-all-categories/293001#29300) is not a change to what my file already has (copied below). Again, these are established categories and they are all empty.

What am I missing? Or, what should I be looking for?

Edit: if it helps here is the result of `curl -i http://localhost:9200/_cluster/health`

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
content-length: 389

{"cluster_name":"elasticsearch","status":"yellow","timed_out":false,"number_of_nodes":1,"number_of_data_nodes":1,"active_primary_shards":5,"active_shards":5,"relocating_shards":0,"initializing_shards":0,"unassigned_shards":5,"delayed_unassigned_shards":0,"number_of_pending_tasks":0,"number_of_in_flight_fetch":0,"task_max_waiting_in_queue_millis":0,"active_shards_percent_as_number":50.0}
```

Edit: Per the comment below I've included the source of the file `vendor/magento/module-elasticsearch/Model/ResourceModel/Fulltext/Collection/SearchResultApplier.php`:

This is Magento 2.3.2 and I don't make local edits to vendor files.

```
    namespace Magento\Elasticsearch\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection;
    
    use Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection\SearchResultApplierInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\Data\Collection;
    use Magento\Framework\Api\Search\SearchResultInterface;
    
    /**
     * Resolve specific attributes for search criteria.
     */
    class SearchResultApplier implements SearchResultApplierInterface
    {
        /**
         * @var Collection|\Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection
         */
        private $collection;
    
        /**
         * @var SearchResultInterface
         */
        private $searchResult;
    
        /**
         * @param Collection $collection
         * @param SearchResultInterface $searchResult
         */
        public function __construct(
            Collection $collection,
            SearchResultInterface $searchResult
        ) {
            $this->collection = $collection;
            $this->searchResult = $searchResult;
        }
    
        /**
         * @inheritdoc
         */
        public function apply()
        {
            if (empty($this->searchResult->getItems())) {
                $this->collection->getSelect()->where('NULL');
                return;
            }
            $ids = [];
            foreach ($this->searchResult->getItems() as $item) {
                $ids[] = (int)$item->getId();
            }
            $this->collection->setPageSize(null);
            $this->collection->getSelect()->where('e.entity_id IN (?)', $ids);
            $orderList = join(',', $ids);
            $this->collection->getSelect()->reset(\Magento\Framework\DB\Select::ORDER);
            $this->collection->getSelect()->order("FIELD(e.entity_id,$orderList)");
        }
    }
```

Progress: In exceptions.log I have the error:
"type":"query_shard_exception",
"reason":"No mapping found for [position_category_#] in order to sort on"

The whole thing:

```
main.CRITICAL: {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"query_shard_exception","reason":"No mapping found for [position_category_104] in order to sort on","index_uuid":"bLDcJEDeQ_eyRQOQYHppzQ",
"index":"magento2_product_1_v1"}],"type":"search_phase_execution_exception","reason":"all shards failed","phase":"query","grouped":true,"failed_shards":[{"shard":0,"index":"magento2_product_1_v1","node":"ZGUdm6aHRU6RShqrqU3xfQ","reason":{"type":"query_shard_exception","reason":"No mapping found for [position_category_104] in order to sort on","index_uuid":"bLDcJEDeQ_eyRQOQYHppzQ","index":"magento2_product_1_v1"}}]},"status":400} {"exception":"[object] (Elasticsearch\\Common\\Exceptions\\BadRequest400Exception(code: 400): {\"error\":{\"root_cause\":[{\"type\":\"query_shard_exception\",\"reason\":\"No mapping found for [position_category_104] in order to sort on\",\"index_uuid\":\"bLDcJEDeQ_eyRQOQYHppzQ\",\"index\":\"magento2_product_1_v1\"}],\"type\":\"search_phase_execution_exception\",\"reason\":\"all shards failed\",\"phase\":\"query\",\"grouped\":true,\"failed_shards\":[{\"shard\":0,\"index\":\"magento2_product_1_v1\",\"node\":\"ZGUdm6aHRU6RShqrqU3xfQ\",\"reason\":{\"type\":\"query_shard_exception\",\"reason\":\"No mapping found for [position_category_104] in order to sort on\",\"index_uuid\":\"bLDcJEDeQ_eyRQOQYHppzQ\",\"index\":\"magento2_product_1_v1\"}}]},\"status\":400} at /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/src/Elasticsearch/Connections/Connection.php:636)"} []
```

Comment: post this file code - Magento\Elasticsearch\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection\SearchResultApplier.php

Comment: What is the output of the `curl http://localhost:9200/_cat/indices` command execution against your ES instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this by renaming the index. It was by default named "magento2" and I renamed it to "mydomain". Did that and reindexed and the error went away. My guess right now is that reindex wasn't taking for some reason on the default index.

(Stores -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Catalog -> Catalog Search -> Elasticsearch Index Prefix)

I was asked for the results of `curl http://localhost:9200/_cat/indices`

Here it is now:

```
yellow open mydomain_product_1_v1     vAbKxQUiQkS7uHdmp-uDCg 5 1 1484 0 1.3mb 1.3mb
yellow open magento2_product_1_v1     bLDcJEDeQ_eyRQOQYHppzQ 5 1    0 0 1.2kb 1.2kb
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sore to select website in the stock settings. [image]