# Magento2 Unable to find products matching the selection

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, php-7.1

Need help to fix the following issue.

> Unable to find products matching your selection.
> https://prnt.sc/EXEuYYFvItge

On debug file we can see the following error message.

```
> [2023-08-07 21:35:00] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate: 
> {"method":"GET","url":"https://website.com/","invalidateInfo":{"identifier":"interception"}}
> [] [2023-08-07 21:35:06] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate: 
> {"method":"GET","url":"https://website.com/","invalidateInfo":{"identifier":"SYSTEM_CONFIG"}}
> [] [2023-08-07 21:39:43] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate: 
> {"method":"GET","url":"https://website.com/customer/account/login/referer/aHR0cHM6Ly9sZWRlZmlzY2FkLmNvbS9wYXBldGVyaWUtZm91cm5pdHVyZXMuaHRtbD9jYXQ9MzEwJnByaWNlPTUwMDAtNjAwMCUyQzIwMDAtJTJDMzAwLSUyQzIwMC0,/","invalidateInfo":{"identifier":"interception"}}
> [] [2023-08-07 21:39:43] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate: 
> {"method":"GET","url":"https://website.com/adminer-4.2.4-pl.php?greensf05/efead350533.htm","invalidateInfo":{"identifier":"interception"}}
> [] [2023-08-07 21:39:48] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate: 
> {"method":"GET","url":"https://website.com/customer/account/login/referer/aHR0cHM6Ly9sZWRlZmlzY2FkLmNvbS9wYXBldGVyaWUtZm91cm5pdHVyZXMuaHRtbD9jYXQ9MzEwJnByaWNlPTUwMDAtNjAwMCUyQzIwMDAtJTJDMzAwLSUyQzIwMC0,/","invalidateInfo":{"identifier":"SYSTEM_CONFIG"}}
> [] [2023-08-07 21:39:52] main.DEBUG: URI
> '/checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cHM6Ly9sZWRlZmlzY2FkLmNvbS9wYXBldGVyaWUtZm91cm5pdHVyZXMuaHRtbD9wcmljZT00MDAwLTUwMDAlMkMzMDAt/product/844/support/''
> cannot be accessed with GET method
> (Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Add) [] []
```

I have run several comand line but nothing work.
php -dmemory_limit=5G bin/magento s:up
php -dmemory_limit=5G bin/magento s:s:d -f en_US fr_FR
php -dmemory_limit=5G bin/magento c:f

Please your help bro.

Comment: You can try reindex by running the command: `bin/magento indexer:reindex`. In your server, you may need: `php -dmemory_limit=5G bin/magento indexer:reindex`. If the issue persists, can you please let me know which Magento version you are using? I suspect you recently upgraded to Magento 2.4 instead of sticking with Magento 2.3.

Comment: I use Magento ver. 2.3.1 - The issue persists

Comment: Perhaps one of the solutions shared in this topic could be helpful to you.  https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/263739/we-cant-find-products-matching-the-selection

Comment: Thank you bro, I have follow all instruction but nothing work well. Last, for this comand : (sudo systemctl restart elasticsearch) I receive : command not found. this is my OS CloudLinux v8.8.0 STANDARD kvm
cPanel Version 112.0.5.

Comment: I think you don't need to run this command since your site (Magento 2.3) has not yet used Elasticsearch.